# Replace single quote single quote just 1 single quote

Tags: sql-server, replace

Hi I have a table where some of the place names have been stored in correctly
for example a place in the Netherlands is stored as OC A''dam Sloterdijk - two single quotes not a double quote and this needs to be set to OC A'dam Sloterdijk with a single quote

I have tried 
`set StoreNm = Replace(StoreNm, '''', ''')` 
but this just removed all single quotes leaving me with none..

Any ideas

Comment: I'm actually surprised that SQL ran; the 3 single quotes (`'''`) should have resulted in an unclosed quotation error.

Answer (score 3):

Double them up:

```
replace(@a, '''''', '''')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this to replace double quote:

```
UPDATE tableName SET ColumnName = REPLACE( ColumnName ,'\"','\\'');
```

EDIT:

To replace double single quote:

```
UPDATE tableName SET ColumnName = REPLACE( ColumnName ,'''''', '''')
```

Comment: OP asked how to replace a double single quote, not a double quote. A single \ escapes a double quote \", but you would need to use \'\' to escape double quotes.

Comment: Hi @devedv 
That did not appear to work it produces an error message
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '
order by Storenm, StoreNo
'.
The code I used was 
update MyTable
set MyColumn1 = REPLACE(MyColumn1,  '\'\'' ,'\\'')
where MyColumn2 = 'abc' and MyColumn3 = 'xyz';

Comment: if you are replacing double single quotes check the updated query.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 1 single quote with 2:

```
replace(@command,char(39),char(39)+char(39))
```

or

Replace 2 single quotes with 1:

```
replace(@command,char(39)+char(39),char(39))
```